# Why do curved windways sound better on the recorder?

Tags: recorder

Can someone explain to me why curved windways sound  better than straight wind ways in terms of physics?

Comment: Can you offer any support for the assertion that curved windways sound better?

Comment: As someone who has built recorders, I'm not sure there's any difference, except perhaps (as the answer Aaron linked to suggests) for possibly better drainage of condensation.  The only other possibility that comes to mind is that as curved windways are often hand carved, perhaps they are not as perfectly smooth and thus create a more complex tone.  Just speculation though.